ODBC Data Source Administrator Adding USERDSN fails due to system error code 126, looking for uninstalled tableau dll
I am trying to set up a connection in office to aws postgres servers. I'm attempting to add to user dsn in odbc data source administrator. When I go to add PostgresSQL Unicode(x64) ODBC driver i get:
ODBC driver could not be loaded due to system error code 126: The specified module could not be found: C:/ProgramFiles/Tableau/Drivers/psqlODBC/0906/bin/psqlodbc35w.dll

I have uninstalled Tableau a while ago, and this path does not exist. I have installed the odbc driver for postgressql. I'm not sure how to get the Data source administrator to stop looking for this old tableau file.
I have tried reinstalling the ODBC driver, looking for old tableau folders that weren't removed from the uninstaller, etc. Nothing is working here.

Use CCleaner or a similar program to remove leftover registry entries or check this https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-remove-leftovers-uninstalled-software/

try to reconfig your aws env variables
